# WPF ValidationRule with dependency property

Tags: wpf, validation, dependency-properties

Suppose you have a class inheriting from ValidationRule:

```
public class MyValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public string ValidationType { get; set; }
    
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo) {}
}
```

In XAML you are validating like this:

```
<ComboBox.SelectedItem>
    <Binding Path="MyPath" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" NotifyOnValidationError="True">
        <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <qmvalidation:MyValidationRule  ValidationType="notnull"/>
        </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
</ComboBox.SelectedItem>
```

Which works and everything is ok.

But suppose now, you want to have `ValidationType="{Binding MyBinding}"` where `MyBinding` comes from `DataContext`.

For this purpose I would need to make `MyValidationRule` as a `DependencyObject` and add a **Dependency Property**.

I've tried to write a class that is `DependencyObject`, and bind it. There are 2 problems though.. the `ValidationRule` DOES NOT have the `DataContext` from the Combobox / Item.

Do you have any ideas, on how to solve that?

Answer (score 36):

Since `ValidationRule` does not inherit from `DependencyObject` you cannot create a `DependecyProperty` in your custom validation class.

However as explained in [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/982e2fcf-780f-4f1c-9730-cedcd4e24320/) you can have a normal property in your validation class which is of a type that inherits from `DependecyObject` and create a `DependencyProperty` in that class.

For example here is a custom `ValidationRule` class that support bindable property:

```
[ContentProperty("ComparisonValue")]
public class GreaterThanValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public ComparisonValue ComparisonValue { get; set; }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        string s = value?.ToString();
        int number;

        if (!Int32.TryParse(s, out number))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Not a valid entry");
        }

        if (number <= ComparisonValue.Value)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, $"Number should be greater than {ComparisonValue}");
        }

        return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    }
}
```

`ComparisonValue` is a simple class that inherits from `DependencyObject` and has a `DependencyProperty`:

```
public class ComparisonValue : DependencyObject
{
    public int Value
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(Value),
        typeof(int),
        typeof(ComparisonValue),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(int));
```

---

This solves the original problem but unfortunately brings two more problems:

1. The binding does not work correctly since the `ValidationRules` is not part of visual tree and therefore cannot get the bound property correctly. For example this naive approach will not work:

   ```
   <TextBox Name="TextBoxToValidate">
       <TextBox.Text>
           <Binding Path="ViewModelProperty" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
               <Binding.ValidationRules>
                   <numbers:GreaterThanValidationRule>
                       <numbers:ComparisonValue Value="{Binding Text, ElementName=TextBoxToValidate}"/>
                   </numbers:GreaterThanValidationRule>
               </Binding.ValidationRules>
           </Binding>
       </TextBox.Text>
   </TextBox>
   ```

   Instead a proxy object should be used as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7661689/3670437) answer:

   ```
   <TextBox Name="TextBoxToValidate">
       <TextBox.Resources>
           <bindingExtensions:BindingProxy x:Key="TargetProxy" Data="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=TextBoxToValidate}"/>
       </TextBox.Resources>
       <TextBox.Text>
           <Binding Path="ViewModelProperty" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
               <Binding.ValidationRules>
                   <numbers:GreaterThanValidationRule>
                       <numbers:ComparisonValue Value="{Binding Data, Source={StaticResource TargetProxy}}"/>
                   </numbers:GreaterThanValidationRule>
               </Binding.ValidationRules>
           </Binding>
       </TextBox.Text>
   </TextBox>
   ```

   `BindingProxy` is a simple class:

   ```
   public class BindingProxy : Freezable
   {
       protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
       {
           return new BindingProxy();
       }

       public object Data
       {
           get { return GetValue(DataProperty); }
           set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
       }
       public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Data), typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
   }
   ```

---

2. If the property in custom `ValidationRule` is bound to another object's property, the validation logic for the original property will not fire when that other object's property changes.

   To solve this problem we should update the binding when the `ValidationRule`'s bound property is updated. First we should bind that property to our `ComparisonValue` class. Then, we can update the source of the binding when the `Value` property changes:

   ```
   public class ComparisonValue : DependencyObject
   {
       public int Value
       {
           get { return (int)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
           set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
       }
       public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
           nameof(Value),
           typeof(int),
           typeof(ComparisonValue),
           new PropertyMetadata(default(int), OnValueChanged));

       private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
       {
           ComparisonValue comparisonValue = (ComparisonValue) d;
           BindingExpressionBase bindingExpressionBase = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpressionBase(comparisonValue, BindingToTriggerProperty);
           bindingExpressionBase?.UpdateSource();
       }

       public object BindingToTrigger
       {
           get { return GetValue(BindingToTriggerProperty); }
           set { SetValue(BindingToTriggerProperty, value); }
       }
       public static readonly DependencyProperty BindingToTriggerProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
           nameof(BindingToTrigger),
           typeof(object),
           typeof(ComparisonValue),
           new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(object), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
   }
   ```

   The same proxy problem in the first case also exists here. Therefore we should create another proxy object:

   ```
   <ItemsControl Name="SomeCollection" ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModelCollectionSource}"/>

   <TextBox Name="TextBoxToValidate">
       <TextBox.Resources>
           <bindingExtensions:BindingProxy x:Key="TargetProxy" Data="{Binding Path=Items.Count, ElementName=SomeCollection}"/>
           <bindingExtensions:BindingProxy x:Key="SourceProxy" Data="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=TextBoxToValidate, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
       </TextBox.Resources>
       <TextBox.Text>
           <Binding Path="ViewModelProperty" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
               <Binding.ValidationRules>
                   <numbers:GreaterThanValidationRule>
                       <numbers:ComparisonValue Value="{Binding Data, Source={StaticResource TargetProxy}}" BindingToTrigger="{Binding Data, Source={StaticResource SourceProxy}}"/>
                   </numbers:GreaterThanValidationRule>
               </Binding.ValidationRules>
           </Binding>
       </TextBox.Text>
   </TextBox>
   ```

   In this case the `Text` property of `TextBoxToValidate` is validated against the `Items.Count` property of `SomeCollection`. When the number of items in the list changes, the validation for the `Text` property will be triggered.

Comment: //<Binding Path="ViewModelProperty" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">// This fires on every key stroke. I wan this to go only after lost focus. But changing this to lost focus is not triggering the validation rule. Any ideas? @Yusuf