# Bind to multiple Properties in UWP

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, uwp, multibinding

In a C# project, I have a complex model using lots of classes nested in lists and dictionaries (e.g. object `A` has a list of instances of `B`, which have a dictionary where values are instances of `C`).
In one of my pages, this model is shown in a complex view using nested `ItemsControl`s.

In addition, there is a `Settings` class which stores user preferences, some of which are bound to checkboxes on the page.

Now, I want to bind properties of some controls within the `DataTemplate`s to a combination of a model property and a setting. For example, let's say that `C` has a property `IsBoring`, and there is a settings `Settings.HideBoringStuff`. I want to bind the visibility of the `TextBlock` representing `C` to the obvious combination of these properties.

I have no idea how to do that without ugly hacks.
Here are a few of my ideas and why they don't work:

- Use a `MultiBinding`, which is specifically designed to do this. However, `MultiBinding` is not available in UWP projects.
- [Bind to multiple properties on the page that implement the logic in their getters and setters.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4835870/926412) This doesn't work because I'm inside a `DataTemplate`, so I need multiple independent copies of this logic.
- Use a `Converter` to convert the model property, passing in the setting as a `ConverterProperty`. However, the `ConverterProperty` is [n](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15309008/926412)[o](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4388326/926412) `DependencyProperty` and therefore cannot be bound.
- Build the needed properties right into the model – `Settings` is a singleton anyway. This feels really ugly, as I'd be mixing unnecessary dependencies and view logic into my model.
- Build separate classes that wrap the model classes, also store the `Settings` object to use, and then offer the combined properties. This feels really ugly too, as I'd need to replicate the whole object hierarchy of the model. (In the example, `ViewA` needs to offer a list of `ViewB`s, each of which have a dictionary where the values are the corresponding `ViewC`s.)
- [Wait for Microsoft to bring `MultiBinding` back.](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/253374-missing-platform-apis/suggestions/5977433-missing-xaml-databinding-features-from-full-wpf) Unluckily, I'm lacking the required optimism.

Which are clean ways to do this in a UWP application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

True that Multibinding hasn't been around on the new win dev stacks. BUT Cimbalino toolkit has had it since early wp8 days.
It also has an UWP port.

So maybe try that!

Blogpost from the early days explaining the use: https://www.pedrolamas.com/2013/05/17/cimbalino-windows-phone-toolkit-multibindingbehavior/
Getting hold of Cimbalino is done through nuget and is available on Github here https://github.com/Cimbalino/Cimbalino-Toolkit

Comment: This looks promising, thanks! I'll look into that soon.

Comment: I hope it will fix your problem :)

Comment: It's actually working! Still, at design time, the XAML parser shows an error (`collection property __implicit_items is null`). Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Hmm no not seen that error before, if you suspect Cimbalino you could ping PedroLamas on Twitter he is very helpful

Comment: PedroLamas already fixed this and will push a new version soon. Hooray! (Actually, it didn't just show the error - it also crashed in release mode...)

Comment: Haaa it is that rd file problem, ok got it :)