# WPF Error: Cannot find governing FrameworkElement for target element

Tags: wpf, image, binding, datagrid, multidatatrigger

I've got a `DataGrid` with a row that has an image. This image is bound with a trigger to a certain state. When the state changes I want to change the image.

The template itself is set on the `HeaderStyle` of a `DataGridTemplateColumn`. This template has some bindings. The first binding Day shows what day it is and the State changes the image with a trigger.

These properties are set in a ViewModel.

Properties:

```cs
public class HeaderItem
{
    public string Day { get; set; }
    public ValidationStatus State { get; set; }
}

this.HeaderItems = new ObservableCollection<HeaderItem>();
for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++)
{
    this.HeaderItems.Add(new HeaderItem()
    {
        Day = i.ToString(),
        State = ValidationStatus.Nieuw,
    });
}
```

Datagrid:

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="PersoneelsPrestatiesDataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding CaregiverPerformances}" FrozenColumnCount="1" >

    <DataGridTemplateColumn HeaderStyle="{StaticResource headerCenterAlignment}" Header="{Binding HeaderItems[1]}" Width="50">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{ Binding Performances[1].Duration,Converter={StaticResource timeSpanConverter},Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Text="{ Binding Performances[1].Duration,Converter={StaticResource timeSpanConverter}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn> 
</DataGrid>
```

Datagrid HeaderStyleTemplate:

```xml
<Style x:Key="headerCenterAlignment" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Day}" />
                    <Image x:Name="imageValidation" Grid.Row="1" Width="16" Height="16" Source="{StaticResource imgBevestigd}" />
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger >
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding State}" Value="Nieuw"/>                                 
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter TargetName="imageValidation" Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource imgGeenStatus}"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now when I startup the project the images doesn't show and I get this error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=HeaderItems[0]; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridTemplateColumn' (HashCode=26950454); target property is 'Header' (type 'Object')

Why is this error showing?

Comment: I checked above answered solution, but it does not work in my case. When I switch to another solution as in link http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/. The idea is the same as solution, instead of using FrameworkElement, they created another class. Then it works for me.

Comment: For others ending up here by searching for the error message: The answer of this similar question helped me to solve the problem fairly easily http://stackoverflow.com/a/18657986/4961688

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Sadly any `DataGridColumn` hosted under `DataGrid.Columns` is not part of `Visual` tree and therefore not connected to the data context of the datagrid. So bindings do not work with their properties such as `Visibility` or `Header` etc (although these properties are valid dependency properties!).

Now you may wonder how is that possible? Isn't their `Binding` property supposed to be bound to the data context? Well it  simply is a hack. The binding does not really work. It is actually the datagrid cells that **copy** / **clone** this binding object and use it for displaying their own contents!

So now back to solving your issue, I assume that `HeaderItems` is a property of the object that is set as the `DataContext` of your parent View. We *can* connect the `DataContext` of the view to any `DataGridColumn` via something we call a **`ProxyElement`**.

The example below illustrates how to connect a logical child such as `ContextMenu` or `DataGridColumn` to the parent View's `DataContext`

```
 <Window x:Class="WpfApplicationMultiThreading.Window5"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
         xmlns:vb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
         Title="Window5" Height="300" Width="300" >
  <Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <FrameworkElement x:Key="ProxyElement" DataContext="{Binding}"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.DataContext>
         <TextBlock Text="Text Column Header" Tag="Tag Columne Header"/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <ContentControl Visibility="Collapsed"
             Content="{StaticResource ProxyElement}"/>
    <vb:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="MyDataGrid">
        <vb:DataGrid.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <TextBlock Text="1" Tag="1.1"/>
                <TextBlock Text="2" Tag="1.2"/>
                <TextBlock Text="3" Tag="2.1"/>
                <TextBlock Text="4" Tag="2.2"/>
            </x:Array>
        </vb:DataGrid.ItemsSource>
        <vb:DataGrid.Columns>
            <vb:DataGridTextColumn
                       Header="{Binding DataContext.Text,
                                     Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}}"
                       Binding="{Binding Text}"/>
            <vb:DataGridTextColumn
                       Header="{Binding DataContext.Tag,
                                     Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}}"
                       Binding="{Binding Tag}"/>
        </vb:DataGrid.Columns>
    </vb:DataGrid>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

The view above encountered the same binding error that you have found if I did not have implemented the ProxyElement hack. The ProxyElement is any FrameworkElement that **steals** the `DataContext` from the main View and offers it to the logical child such as `ContextMenu` or `DataGridColumn`. For that it must be hosted as a `Content` into an invisible `ContentControl` which is under the same View.

I hope this guides you in correct direction.

Comment: I find having to use this hacky proxy stuff really disapointing but I cannot find another way to achieve the same functionality otherwise... Thank you.

Comment: This didn't work for me but after reading Josh Smith's article about Virtual Branches I tried adding the OneWayToSource binding on my root control to set the "ProxyElement" DataContext and that worked.

Comment: @jpierson, are you using `Silverlight`? Coz it works for me in `WPF`. For silverlight the implementation is different.

Comment: I'm using WPF but I'm using .NET 3.5 if that matters.

Comment: Nope. The solution above fits for .NET 3.5 very well.

Comment: This answer is old, but still useful against .NET 4.0.
Lots of the answers around involving copying the DataContext to the column don't seem to work.
I needed to show/hide a column depending on a view model property and this solution worked well.
And with no code behind won't cause a diplomatic incident in the code review.

Comment: I can't tell if this is the DataGrid in WPFToolkit or the one built-in to .NET 4.0, but I'm using a DataGridTextColumn and the Visibility binding works fine for me without using this workaround.  However, at runtime I get the same warning as KDP and can't figure out how to get rid of it.

Comment: FYI Context menu is not the same and has a non-proxy work around. Context menu has an exposed property `Parent` whereas the `DataGridTextColumn` does not expose its `DataGridOwner` property. See how a context items binding is accomplished via RelativeSource binding in my answer [Context Menu Binding to Parent Window's Datacontext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26359091/context-menu-binding-to-parent-windows-datacontext/26383463#26383463)

Comment: In your solution yopu have specified ContextMenu` under a `FrameworkElement` in XAML.... 

But MSDN says... "Parent may be a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) in cases where an element was instantiated, but is not attached to any **logical** tree that eventually connects to the page level root element, or the application object." ... 

Due to this if your context menu is a WPF `Resource` it wont have `Parent` but will still have a `DataContext` due to `ProxyElement`. So the point is `ProxyElement` works in Popups, DataGridColumns, `ContextMenu` etc.

Comment: +1 :) this is golden (even as a hack) - this works on very different scenarios described by @WPF-it, as long as the error is the same - e.g. in one case I used a proxy inside a `ListBox.ItemTemplate` as this is also typical for `ItemsControl` (it involves a very custom binding scenario - flags generated checkbox list) - great and thanks, you learn something every day.

Comment: This answer did not work for me. Thanks @leo5th Here's a similar solution that works: http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/

Comment: Man.. what a *hack*... it worked when I had to bind `CollectionContainer.Collection`, thanks

Answer (score 21):

A slightly shorter alternative to using a `StaticResource` as in the accepted answer is `x:Reference`:

```xml
<StackPanel>

    <!--Set the DataContext here if you do not want to inherit the parent one-->
    <FrameworkElement x:Name="ProxyElement" Visibility="Collapsed"/>

    <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn
                Header="{Binding DataContext.Whatever, Source={x:Reference ProxyElement}}"
                Binding="{Binding ...}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

</StackPanel>
```

The main advantage of this is: if you already have an element which is **not** a DataGrid's ancestor (i.e. **not** the `StackPanel` in the example above), you can just give it a name and use it as the `x:Reference` instead, hence not needing to define any dummy `FrameworkElement` at all.

If you try referencing an ancestor, you will get a `XamlParseException` at run-time due to a cyclical dependency.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! Wonder why we have to go through this trouble though

Comment: This is producing runtime error ```DataContext property not found on object of type Reference.```

Answer (score 0):

The way without a proxy is to set bindings in the constructor:

```cs
var i = 0;
var converter = new BooleanToVisibilityConverter();
foreach(var column in DataGrid.Columns)
{
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(column, DataGridColumn.VisibilityProperty, new Binding($"Columns[{i++}].IsSelected")
    { 
        Source = ViewModel,
        Converter = converter,
    });
}
```