# Dynamically change the WPF Datagrid column header

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I am using wpf toolkit datagrid in wpf win applications. In my view model, I have a observablecollection property which is binded to the itemsource of the datagrid.
Student class is having Name, Age, Class properties and displays in each columns in the grid.

But I have a property called "Header1" in my View model class and how i can bind it to the Header of the data grid text column ? When I used, it is not displaying the header string in the grid. I need to update this column header at run time. How I can do that ? I also tried the following way;

```
<dg:DataGridColumn Header = "{Binding Header1, ElementName=MyUsrCtrl}" />
```

BUT this is also not working ? I used `DataContext.Header1, ElementName=MyUsrCtrl` also...but no use.

How it is possible ?

Comment: Why are you using ElementName if you're binding to a property in your view model class?

Comment: Can you show bit of your xaml code?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot bind to any daatgrid columns as they are not part of the visual tree. Use the proxy element trick.

[WPF Error: Cannot find governing FrameworkElement for target element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660967/wpf-error-cannot-find-govering-frameworkelement-for-target-element/7661689#7661689)

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing much about your code, I'm just taking a stab at this, but here we go.  I'm assuming you've bound your entire view to your view model using `DataContext`, and that you're binding `ItemsSource` for the `DataGrid` something like this:

```
<dg:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" />
```

Assuming that's true, you're most of the way there with your header binding.  Just remove the ElementName portion of the binding like so:

```
<dg:DataGridColumn Header = "{Binding Header1}" />
```

That should do the trick.  One other thing to note is to make sure that your view model implements [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) and that the setter for the `Header1` property calls your `PropertyChanged` method for itself.