# DataGridTextColumn binding issue

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I am having trouble binding to `IsReadOnly` on a`DataGridTextColumn`.

```
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=OffsetRelative}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly}">
                                    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <CheckBox Content="Relative Offset" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=ViewReportFileUserControl, Path=DataContext.IsSelectedTcfOffsetRelative}" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Both `OffsetRelative` and `IsReadOnly` are public properties in the same class.  The Binding to `OffsetRelative` works fine but the Binding to `IsReadOnly` generates the following run time output:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement
>   or FrameworkContentElement for target element.
>   BindingExpression:Path=IsReadOnly; DataItem=null; target element is
>   'DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=2149042); target property is
>   'IsReadOnly' (type 'Boolean')

Why would one binding work and not the other?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660967/wpf-error-cannot-find-govering-frameworkelement-for-target-element

Comment: Is it a boolean property?  And is it returning a null?