# Binding to parent DataContext from ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am struggling with binding to parent DataContext from DataTemplate/ContextMenu control. I've already tried solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36043659/how-to-bind-a-command-to-a-contextmenu-from-within-an-itemtemplate?lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668654/relativesource-binding-from-a-tooltip-or-contextmenu?noredirect=1&lq=1) but with no luck. I'm not able to bind to neither to property or command - no exceptions are thrown, but commands are not invoked and properties are set to null.

Here's my code sample (simplified as its possible):

```
<Metro:MetroWindow ...>
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MyViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel ... />
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <Border ... />
        <ListBox x:Name="FileList" ItemsSource="{Binding AddedFiles}" Margin="5,5,5,5" SelectionMode="Multiple" SelectionChanged="ItemsSelectionChanged">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel MaxWidth="700" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FileListItem}">
                    <Grid Margin="5" Width="110" ToolTip="{Binding Path=TooltipInfo}" MouseDown="FileItemClick" Tag="{Binding DataContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}">
                        <Grid.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Header="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.test,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" />
                                <MenuItem Header="Test command" Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.CloseCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </Grid.ContextMenu>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions ... />
                        <StackPanel ...(Databinding works here!) />
                        <TextBlock ... (Databinding works here!) />
                        <Rectangle ... (Databinding works here!) />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I've tried to bind Tag property with Window's DataContext via RelativeSource too (and other possible solutions found across other topics), but nothing happens. Something must be clearly wrong in my approach.

Comment: CloseCommand this command is in FileListItem?

Comment: @WPFUser Nope, Its inside ViewModel (parent DataContext). Thats the idea - to invoke command from parent DataContext using ContextMenu from single FileListItem

Comment: then you should be accessing  ListBox's DataContext. Not its Item datacontext.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot find PlacementTarget property in Grid. Change your binding like this,

```
 <MenuItem Header="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.test,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" />
```

or like,

```
<MenuItem Header="{Binding Parent.PlacementTarget.Tag.test,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

Also To access ViewModel's command, Access DataContext of ListBox not ListBoxItem,

```
 <Grid Margin="5" Width="110" ToolTip="{Binding Path=TooltipInfo}" MouseDown="FileItemClick" Tag="{Binding DataContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode= FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBox}}">
```

Comment: Accessing DataContext of ListBoxItem instead of ListBox was the reason of problem - I didn't notice, that relating to Grid gives single list item context. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? (note **DataContext** added)

```
<MenuItem Header="{Binding DataContext.PlacementTarget.Tag.test,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Grid}}" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't change anything, but thanks for reply.