# DataGridColumn Readonly via converter

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, converters, datagridcolumn

I have a Datagrid with three columns.

**I want the second column readonly if the value of first column is not null**

I tried with a converter but there's something wrong.
Any ideas why?

```
<UserControl.Resources
    <Converters:StringToBoolConverter x:Key="stringToBoolConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

   .......................................

<DataGrid Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="_edgFAI" AddCommandVisibility="Visible" InternalCommandsHandling="False" DeleteCommandVisibility="Visible" SaveCommandVisibility="Visible">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="IdenFAI" Tag="ID_FAI" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Tag="DS_FAI" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=ID_FAI, Converter={StaticResource stringToBoolConverter}}" />
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="DocumentState" Tag="FAI_STATE" Width="SizeToHeader" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: write some comments before say that is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into output log, you'll most probably notice this error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element.

Column definition does not reside in the visual tree, so `IsReadOnly` property does not bind to any data context realted item. For more in-depth explanation see the answer for this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7661689/1021555).

You can use that solution, but alternatively you can just set the style of editing element:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Name}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" 
                    Value="{Binding Path=ID_FAI, Converter={StaticResource stringToBoolConverter}}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Or use a template column and define your own editing template (which will be similar anyway).