# Unable to set DataPointsSource in an XCeed Chart

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, charts, xceed-plus-edition

I work on that problem from one day, I use a XCeed chart in WPF,like this :

```
    <xceedTk:Chart Name="graphComptage" VerticalAlignment="Top"  MinWidth="400"  MinHeight="400" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" IsEnabled="True" 
                         BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" DataContext="{Binding}"
                         Visibility="{Binding AfficherErreur, Converter={conv:BoolConverter TrueValue=Collapsed, FalseValue=Visible}}">
                <xceedTk:Chart.Legend>
                    <xceedTk:Legend Title="{Binding TitreLegende}" Width="{Binding LargeurLegende}" Height="Auto" BorderThickness="0" />
                </xceedTk:Chart.Legend>
                <xceedTk:Chart.Areas>
                    <xceedTk:Area Title="{Binding TitreLegende}">
                        <xceedTk:Axis Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0 0 5 0" ShowGridLines="True" GraduationMode="Automatic" LabelsType="DateTime"  />
                        <xceedTk:Axis Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 0 5 0" ShowGridLines="True" GraduationMode="Automatic" LabelsType="Numeric" />
                        <xceedTk:Area.Series>
                            <xceedTk:Series DataPointsSource="{Binding DataContext.SeriesPoints, ElementName=ucVueTabulaireGraphique}">
                                <xceedTk:Series.Layout>
                                    <xceedTk:LineLayout />
                                </xceedTk:Series.Layout>
                                <xceedTk:Series.DataPointBindings>
                                    <xceedTk:BindingInfo PropertyName="Y">
                                        <xceedTk:BindingInfo.Binding>
                                            <Binding Path="Value"/>
                                        </xceedTk:BindingInfo.Binding>
                                    </xceedTk:BindingInfo>
                                    <xceedTk:BindingInfo PropertyName="X">
                                        <xceedTk:BindingInfo.Binding>
                                            <Binding Path="Key"/>
                                        </xceedTk:BindingInfo.Binding>
                                    </xceedTk:BindingInfo>
                                </xceedTk:Series.DataPointBindings>
                            </xceedTk:Series>
                        </xceedTk:Area.Series>
                    </xceedTk:Area>
                </xceedTk:Chart.Areas>
            </xceedTk:Chart>
```

[(All the XAML file is here)](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ag2AA8qTGoVAmeZefubCl0rbdb8YaA)

I want to bind this on a dictionary in my ViewModel, when I check in the output window, I have in all time a similar message :

```
    System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.SeriesPoints; DataItem=null; target element is 'Series' (HashCode=49725882); target property is 'DataPointsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')
```

It seems that I cannot access at the public property in the view Model, I tried various manner to bind to my ViewModel properties, (FindAncestor, directly), but I always have the same result.

Does somebody stil have an idea?

Comment: What is ucVueTabulaireGraphique and where is your view model?

Comment: ucVueTabulaireGraphique is a UsersControl and my ViewModel is bind to the DataContext of this UserControl. In my ViewModel I have this properties:
        public List<Series> SeriesPoints
        {
            get => _seriesPoints;
            set
            {
                _seriesPoints = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

Comment: Is the Chart a child of the UserControl...?

Comment: No there is a lot of thing before. This user is in a tabcontrol too.

Comment: Unless you think someone will be able to guess how your XAML is structured, you should post it if you want any help.

Comment: I put the XAML file on link.

Comment: Is this for the **paid** version of the toolkit?

Comment: Eventually, yes, but for the moment, I don't have a good experience, I was with DataVisualizationToolKit before, very much easier to implements, and for me the look and feel was better, but it have a memory leak, we need to change the control.

Comment: Ok... I'm asking because I wanted to create a specific tag for the paid versions, so I'm looking for potential users...:O) otherwise the tag gets dropped/refused.

Comment: So, I want to tag your question with `xceed-plus-edition` (new tag), if that's ok with you. This is justifiable since the XAML for this edition is different from the community version.

Comment: It is perfect for me, there is not a lot of documentation for the paid edition, and I have a lot a difficulties to get information. 

The case i want to do is so simple, it just a graph with a (1...n) series, (linear, graphic), For the moment, I have a lot a difficulties with the binding but I am looking for example in the project sample and I don't see anything representing something similar to the final result I need in my application.

Comment: I'm looking into your binding problem. I get the very same binding error you did in a much simpler scenario. If you google that error, **Cannot find governing FrameworkElement** you will find out that one solution is _stealing the DataContext_... which quite frankly sucks...:O) The reason for this, from what I read, is that sometimes some parts of the control is not in the visual tree, causing the problem...

Comment: Take a look at [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660967/wpf-error-cannot-find-governing-frameworkelement-for-target-element).

Comment: Yes I tried that solution too, I think I will stop wasting my time with that control and try another one.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you're using a `Dictionary` alone could be the problem because it does not implement the necessary notification interfaces required for proper binding. In general, use an `ObservableCollection` instead. In particular, `Xceed` components, based on their own sample code, seem to favor the usage of `CollectionViewSource`. So, here's some working sample code for you:

[See resulting chart image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5Ud3.png)

**XAML:**

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit" 
        x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs1" Source="{Binding Data}"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MyViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <xctk:Chart>
            <xctk:Chart.Areas>
                <xctk:Area>
                    <xctk:Area.Series>
                        <xctk:Series DataPointsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs1}}">
                            <xctk:Series.Layout>
                                <xctk:LineLayout />
                            </xctk:Series.Layout>
                            <xctk:Series.DataPointBindings>
                                <xctk:BindingInfo PropertyName="X">
                                    <xctk:BindingInfo.Binding>
                                        <Binding Path="Item1"/>
                                    </xctk:BindingInfo.Binding>
                                </xctk:BindingInfo>
                                <xctk:BindingInfo PropertyName="Y">
                                    <xctk:BindingInfo.Binding>
                                        <Binding Path="Item2"/>
                                    </xctk:BindingInfo.Binding>
                                </xctk:BindingInfo>
                            </xctk:Series.DataPointBindings>
                        </xctk:Series>
                    </xctk:Area.Series>
                </xctk:Area>
            </xctk:Chart.Areas>
        </xctk:Chart>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**View Model:**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Tuple<int,int>> Data { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Data = new ObservableCollection<Tuple<int, int>>();

        Random y = new Random();

        for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++)
            Data.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(x, y.Next(100)));

    }
}
```

Note that, although it uses a `StaticResource` in the binding statement, if you dynamically updated the underlying `Data` property in the view model, the chart will dynamically update as well.