# How to pass a custom class Property as an argument to a validation rule in WPF (TextBox)

Tags: wpf, textbox, validationrule

I have the following code for my textbox

```
<TextBox
    ....>
  <TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="Latitude" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
      <Binding.ValidationRules>
        <c:LatitudeValidator>
      </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</Text>
```

But I need an ISession property (of the View) to be passed to the property of the validation rule

Comment: Here is good sample https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46519802/how-to-bind-values-from-xaml-to-validation-rule

Comment: That works fine for pre-defined values, but what if in validation I need access to the actual "model". This works for my original question because ISession is pretty generic, but on validation of other fields, I need to access the Model.

Comment: It works for non constant values good. For predefined values there is simpler way with Dependence Property in the rule. Wrapper let you pass whatever you want. I used this way for checking with comparison two viewmodel’s properties.

Comment: Look at acceptable answer in that question sample with wrapper.